# Hybrid app get store where is released

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store

I'm developing an hybrid app with Ionic. I've some functionality which can be used only in some states so I want to disable these functionality elsewhere. Is possible to understand from which store the app has been downloaded or, similary, get the default nation of device?

The app is for iOS and Android.

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check what OS the app is being loaded. Look at http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/

Specially:

```
var isIOS = ionic.Platform.isIOS();
var isAndroid = ionic.Platform.isAndroid();
```

As far as `nation` (as in "country")... you would need Geolocation services. Check https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation

Comment: Well I feel so stupid, I didn't think about Geolocation. Thanks you

Comment: No worries, I feel the same way from time to time ;) If I pointed you in the right direction, don't forget to accept the answer to help others in the community with similar problems.